# How use xpath queries in PHPQuery?

Tags: php, phpquery

I'm looking for an example code how use xpath [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). 
I read the wiki-pages but not found any thing. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project summary states

> phpQuery is a server-side, chainable, CSS3 selector driven Document Object Model (DOM) API based on jQuery JavaScript Library.

As XPath is not part of CSS3 selectors and there are no references in the documentation, I'd say it hasn't been implemented.

### Update

From digging through their source, it looks like it wraps `DOMDocument` and you can retrieve the documents from the `phpQuery::$documents` array. Once you have the `DOMDocument` instance, you can perform create a `DOMXPath` object and perform queries on it.

Answer (score 1):

So PHPQuery actually has a function called `protected function getNodeXpath($oneNode = null, $namespace = null)`. You can find it pretty easily if you just look in the [phpquery_onefile](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/downloads/detail?name=phpQuery-0.9.5.386-onefile.zip&can=2&q=).

If you simply change this `protected` function to `public`, you can now use it in your code. You would just need to do something like this: `pq('button')->getNodeXpath()`.

Keep in mind though, this returns an array, and a lot of functions (such as those in [php-webdriver](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/master/lib/WebDriverBy.php)) will require a string xpath. To fix this, simply implode the array you get back.